# fancybox iframe gallery with hashbang urls

Tags: iframe, fancybox, gallery

For a new website I use hashbang method you can overview here: http://mikevalstar.com/Blog/104/Simple_Hashbang_URLs_and_Google

This means I have links like mywebsite.com/#!/realisations, mywebsite.com/#!/contact and so on... This work fine and allows me to load only part of pages with nice transitions...

I also use fancybox to open iframe (video player) and try to use iframe gallery to switch between all my videos. This work fine if I don't use hashbang url: opening iframes gallery from mywebsite.com/realisations to open /videos/myvideo1.html, video2.html, and so on...
But with the added /#!/ (mywebsite.com/#!/realisations) in url, jquery.fancybox.js don't populate the url group (F.group) and open only the first iframe with no prev/next arrows.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: paste your code to see what you have been tried ... or share a link or a fiddle to demonstrate the issue